# Includegraphics slightly greater than linewidth

Tags: includegraphics

I'm trying to load a graphic to fit the `\textwidth`and `\textheight`, i.e., the whole page except the top, bottom, left and right margins. However, when I include the graphic with the `\textwidth` and `\textheight` parameters, it doesn't fit and it is pushed to the next page.

Why is this happening? Can the geometry of the page be changed so the command

```
\inlcudegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight]{filename}
```

works?

PS. I'm not looking for a workaround of the type

```
\inlcudegraphics[width=.9\linewidth, height=.9\textheight]{filename}
```

I want to choose the margins and the picture to use exactly that space.

Current MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm,marginparsep=0cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight, trim={0 0 0 0}]{filename}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37958/high-precision-includegraphics-for-latex

Comment: This explains the "why" part. Useful!

Comment: It also shows solutions. Both adjustbox and the `max totalsize` and Josephs code should work. But I would avoid such exact sizes and always allow for a rounding error.

Comment: Can the rounding error somehow be forced downwards? So that the picture always fits in the margins, even if there's a small white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has always been a problem putting a full page image on the first page.  Every other page is fine.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm,marginparsep=0cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}\smash{%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight, trim={0 0 0 0}]{example-image}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,
            right=1cm,
            top=1cm,
            bottom=1cm,
            marginparsep=0cm,
            showframe
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
% this only to gather some info, not needed for graphics inclusion
\setbox0\hbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                               height=\textheight]{example-image-a}}%
\typeout{\number\wd0, \number\ht0 \space(box)}
\typeout{\number\linewidth, \number\textheight\space(actual text area dimensions)}
% actual graphics inclusion
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize\linewidth
                     \vss
                     \noindent
                     \makebox[\linewidth]{%
                     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                                      height=\textheight]{example-image-a}%
                     }%
                     \vss}


\end{document}
```

And the log contains

```
35430201, 51656780 (box)
35428918, 51651632 (actual text area dimensions)
```

[image]

Note: I also tried replacing `\Gscale@div` with  a more precise one:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,
            right=1cm,
            top=1cm,
            bottom=1cm,
            marginparsep=0cm,
            showframe
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383700/4686
\newcommand\SetToRatio[3]{% sets #1 to be the ratio #2/#3, where #2 and #3 
    % are lengths (registers or expressions).
    % The ratio #2/#3 should evaluate to less than 16384 in absolute value to 
    % avoid arithmetic overflow. It will be computed as fixed point
    % number with about 4 or 5 digits after decimal mark.
    \edef #1%
        {\strip@pt\dimexpr
         \numexpr\dimexpr#2\relax*65536/\dimexpr#3\relax\relax sp\relax}%
}

\let\Gscale@div\SetToRatio
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\setbox0\hbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                               height=\textheight]{example-image-a}}%
\typeout{\number\wd0, \number\ht0 \space(box)}
\typeout{\number\linewidth, \number\textheight\space(actual text area dimensions)}

\vbox to \textheight{\hsize\linewidth
                     \vss
                     \noindent
                     \makebox[\linewidth]{%
                     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                                      height=\textheight]{example-image-a}%
                     }%
                     \vss}


\end{document}
```

but the log file then contains

```
35428916, 51651721 (box)
35428918, 51651632 (actual text area dimensions)
```

so the height is still bigger than `\textheight` although the width is much more precise. And the image without wrapping is still pushed to next page.

I also tried the `\divdef` at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383700/4686 and it gives exact same result as using the above e-TeX dependent approach.

Notice that then you can use

```
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                          height=\dimexpr\textheight-50sp\relax]{example-image-a}
```

With the non-patched graphicx, this works: (65536sp = 1pt)

```
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                          height=\dimexpr\textheight-5150sp\relax]{example-image-a}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm,marginparsep=0cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight, trim={0 0 0 0}]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It shows in the right place, but the figure is bigger than the textwidth, I believe. Plus, it doesn't make sense using a floating element when I want a fixed position.